# How to improve results recognition with Tesseract?

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, text-recognition

I am using picture

[image]

And i want to recognize numbers from it

```
var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractOnly);
engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(@"D:/Ex.png");
var page = engine.Process(img);
var text = page.GetText();
Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Result is very bad `31 3 963`
How to improve it?

Comment: Add `/` character in whitelist `engine.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789/");`

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan, It does not help result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can train your own tessdata file using your pic replacing the eng.
Download the source code of tesseract-ocr from github(https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract),and read the wiki(https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-3.00–3.02) ,it can help you to train your tessdata.
Hope it helps.